# B2424S-2WR2 supply current

Tags: ground, isolated, ampere-hour

Anyone already use B2424S-2WR2 ?
I want connected it with TSR 1-2450 but still confuse will it can supply good current to TSR 1-2450

here the schematic

[image]

Comment: What is causing your confusion? Your B2424S will output 24V, the TSR 1-245 accepts 24V. Where is the confusion? You have not mentioned how many Amps are involved.

Comment: yes i mean the Amps, sory.

Comment: How many Amps?  1...2.....?